# Having difficulty checking each individual users' hash of randomly generated numbers in an array, instead checks all

Tags: ruby

I am creating a bingo game for the ruby console in which, numbers are randomly put into a hash for each user, comprising of the bingo board, and each user's hash is put into an array of all "bingo boards".   I am having trouble with checking the right answers against these hashes/boards within the array, because it checks the winning columns against all users instead of each individual users board (hash).  The first three information/methods below are used  as backup information, whereas the bottom two methods are where the problem are.  How do I switch the methods to check the winning combinations against one hash in the bingo cards array, and if nothing restart over on the next hash instead of combining from different cards?

The winning combinations are below

```
#here are the winning combinations

@columns = [      
  [:a1,:a2,:a3,:a4,:a5],
  [:b1,:b2,:b3,:b4,:b5],
  [:c1,:c2,:c3,:c4,:c5],
  [:d1,:d2,:d3,:d4,:d5],
  [:e1,:e2,:e3,:e4,:e5],

  [:a1,:b1,:c1,:d1,:e1],
  [:a2,:b2,:c2,:d2,:e2],
  [:a3,:b3,:c3,:d3,:e3],
  [:a4,:b4,:c4,:d4,:e4],
  [:a5,:b5,:c5,:d5,:e5],

  [:a1,:b2,:c3,:d4,:e5],
  [:e1,:d2,:c3,:b4,:a5]
]
```

This method starts a game, and fills up a hash of random bingo numbers into an array for each user.  The array is called @bingo_cards

```
def start_game(user_goes_first)
#bingo slots
@places =  Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = " "  }
@places_keys = [
  :a1,:a2,:a3,:a4,:a5,
  :b1,:b2,:b3,:b4,:b5,
  :c1,:c2,:c3,:c4,:c5,
  :d1,:d2,:d3,:d4,:d5,
  :e1,:e2,:e3,:e4,:e5
]

@bingo_cards = []


fill_cards(@users_count)


user_turn
```

end

this method takes the randomly generated numbers and turns them into bingo cards (hash) and then puts them in array (@bingo_cards)

```
def fill_cards(number)
  number.times do 
    @places_keys.each_with_index do |n,i| 
      @places[n] = pick_number(i)
    end
    @bingo_cards << @places.dup
  end
end
```

This is where the number is picked each time - @user = 'X', so it replaces the number with X

```
def user_turn
  put_line
  puts "\n  RUBY BINGO".purple
  draw_game
  print "\n Please type 'go' or type 'exit' to quit: ".neon
  STDOUT.flush
  input = gets.chomp.downcase.to_str
  put_bar
  if input.length == 2
    @random = rand(1..75)
    puts @random
    @bingo_cards.each do |bingo|
      @places_keys.each do |key|
        bingo[key] = @user if bingo[key] == @random
      end
    end
    put_line
    check_game(@user)
  else
    wrong_input unless input == :exit
  end
end
```

Here is where I am having the problem. It does properly count the X's, but for every user.  Meaning it only works properly if one person is playing.  If two people are playing it if a user has two X's (meaning the number came up) in a row in the the top left, and the other user has three x's in a row in the top right it ends the game - it should only end when a user has 5 X's, aka the random number is picked 5 times on their board.

```
def times_in_column arr, item
 #count the number of X's in the column to see if 5 in a row
  times = 0
  @bingo_cards.each do |bingo|
    arr.each do |i| 
      times += 1 if bingo[i] == item
    end
  end
  times
end
```

This method is responsible for checking the game, alongside the method above.

```
def check_game(next_turn)

  game_over = nil

  @bingo_cards.each do |bingo|
    @columns.each do |column|

    # see if user has won
      if times_in_column(column, @user) == 5
        put_line
        draw_game
        put_line
        puts ""
        puts " Game Over -- WINS!!!\n".blue
        game_over = true
        @user_score += 1
        ask_to_play_again(true)
      end
    end
  end

  unless game_over
    user_turn
  end
end
```

[Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/sml0820/4aaa1e874ac3a82e3d05) for any additional needed information - I commented everything throughout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a problem:

```
def times_in_column arr, item
 #count the number of X's in the column to see if 5 in a row
  times = 0
  @bingo_cards.each do |bingo|
    arr.each do |i| 
      times += 1 if bingo[i] == item
    end
  end
  times
end
```

Consider what happens in the code above. `times_in_column` is called with an array of keys, say the one across the top `[a1:, a2:, a3:, a4:, a5:]`. `times` is set to 0. For each bingo card in play, each key in the array is examined on a card, and if an X is found, `times` is increased. Notice that as the bingo card loop (`@bingo_cards.each do |bingo|`) progresses, `times` is never reset to 0, so the count increases each time an X is found on any bingo card in the loop.

To fix this, I'd suggest moving the bingo card loop out of the `times_in_column` method, and call `times_in_column` on each individual bingo card, then check the return value.

Actually, I'd suggest rewriting this method to take a single bingo card and check all possible winning patterns (in @columns), and for each winning pattern, start the times count at 0, and remember if any of the winning patterns ever found 5 Xs, and return true if this is so, false otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing the results you're seeing because of two factors:

1. You're using the same value of `@user` on all the bingo cards. In
   fact, `@user` never changes.
2. You're adding up the instances of `@user` across *all* bingo cards for each column

If you know which cards a user owns, there is no need for user-specific marks on the cards, as you can just check the card that the user owns. Similarly, if you use unique marks for each user, you can count across all cards *provide that* each user only has one card. If a user can play more than one card, as is common in bingo, then it's still going to be important to look at the columns for each card separately.

BTW, there are *lots* of quality issues with this code, such as recursively calling `user_turn` for each move. I would strongly encourage you to subject this to a code review.